# Splitting Text File Into Columns and Rows in Python

Tags: python

I have a newbie question. I need help on separating a text file into columns and rows. Let's say I have a file like this:

```
1 2 3 4

2 3 4 5
```

and I want to put it into a 2d list called `values = [[]]`

i can get it to give me the rows ok and this code works ok:

```
values = map(int, line.split(','))
```

I just don't know how I can say the same thing but for the rows and the documentation doesn't make any sense

cheers

Comment: @user654174 There is no ',' in your exemple and you split by ',' . Incoherent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = open(filename,'rt')
a = [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in f.readlines()[::2]]
```

In your sample file above, you have an empty line between each data row - I took this into account, but you can drop the `::2` subscript if you didn't mean to have this extra line in your data.

Edit: added conversion to int - you can use `map` as well, but mixing list comprehensions and `map` seems ugly to me.

Comment: If there are no empty lines, he can also drop the `readlines()`.

Comment: hi, the blank line is there because for some reason it put the numbers on the same line so had to put the blank line in to separate them

Comment: Thus: `a = [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in file]` (`file` being a valid file handle i.e. obtained from `open`)

Comment: sorry for being dense, but what does token mean?

Comment: It's just a name - `[int(token) for token in line.split()]` takes each element of the list returned by `line.split()`, names it `token` and executes `int()` on it, thus forming another sequence, which contains all numbers in a line as integers. I could have chosen any other name.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler _"file being a valid file handle i.e. obtained from open"_ Horror !! We must never use names for user's objects that are already names of built-in objects !

Comment: Ok, I have entered the following code [CODE]def columnAndRows():
    filename = 'values.txt', 'r'
    values = [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in filename]
    print values[/CODE] though nothing is being printed out :s

Comment: @eyquem. It's a sample. I chose the name to make clear that I expected him to have a file handle here.

@user. `filename` seems to be the path to the file, not the open file handle! Use `open(filename,'rt')` to get such a handle.

Comment: @ Alexander Gessler Then write  ``for line in file_handler.readlines()`` !

Comment: As you please!                             >

Comment: (Just for information: «When you do want to insert a <br /> break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.»)

Comment: hmmmm....this is frustrating - I have entered the code as kindly given by Alexander, though I am still hitting a brick wall, I get the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' - I have tried putting a comma in the brackets after line.split, though it still complains

Comment: What are your *exact* file contents? (i.e. upload it to pastebin!) I too don't understand where the comma comes from ..

Comment: If you have commas between the values, why didn't you write that in the first place ...

Comment: I get the rows ok but don't get the columns

Comment: what do you mean by 'get the columns'? It returns nested lists, row-order, doesn't it? How exactly do you want the return value to look like? Please try to be more exact in your wording.

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused, I just thought that for each column in my file e.g. the first number of the first column being 0 to the last number of the first column also being 0, would have it's own dimension but I realise now that it does work as it should - so in essence I thought that a column list would be represented by one integer on each line

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import itertools

values = []

with open('text.file') as file_object:
    for line in csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=' '):
        values.append(map(int, line))

print "rows:", values
print "columns"
for column in itertools.izip(*values):
    print column
```

Output is:

```
rows: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
columns:
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
```

Comment: _"I just don't know how I can say the same thing **but for the rows**"_

Answer (score 1):

Get the data into your program by some method.  Here's one:

```
f = open(tetxfile, 'r')
buffer = f.read()
f.close()
```

Parse the buffer into a table (note: strip() is used to clear any trailing whitespace):

```
table = [map(int, row.split()) for row in buffer.strip().split("\n")]

>>> print table
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Maybe it's ordered pairs you want instead, then transpose the table:

```
transpose = zip(*table)
>>> print transpose
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [`CSV`-module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). You can specify custom delimiters, so it might work.

Answer (score 0):

If columns are separated by blanks

```
import re

A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]
pat = re.compile('([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)')

with open('try.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c,d = pat.match(line.strip()).groups()
        A.append(int(a));B.append(int(b));C.append(int(c));D.append(int(d))
```

or with **csv** module

EDIT

```
A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]    
with open('try.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c,d = line.split()
        A.append(int(a));B.append(int(b));C.append(int(c));D.append(int(d))
```

But if there are more than one blank between elements of data, this code will fail

EDIT 2

Because the solution with regex has been qualified of extremely hard to understand, it can be cleared as follows:

```
import re

A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]
pat = re.compile('\s+')

with open('try.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c,d = pat.split(line.strip())
        A.append(int(a));B.append(int(b));C.append(int(c));D.append(int(d))
```

Comment: That is way too complicated for the purpose. Using regular expressions for everything makes code extremely hard to read.

Comment: Also, not using raw strings makes regexes fail. Usually :-)

Comment: @Alexander Gessler I don't write regexes for everything. _"extremely hard"_ : you exagerate. But you are completely right: here, there is no need of regex. So I edit my answer

Comment: @Alexander Gessler  _"not using raw strings makes regexes fail"_ Not for me, I always write RE without raw string, I master the writing of RE without rawing them. In fact, I can't succeed to understand how works a raw string as a RE .....

Comment: `re.compile('\s+')` works only because `\s` is not a recognized escape sequence. Therefore, it is official recommendation to always use raw strings when specifying regexes.

Comment: Regarding `extremely hard`: Using regexes were they are not required (and they are not required if a simple `split()` does the same!) always qualifies as `extremely hard to read` in comparison to the short variant, be it using `csv` or using a simple list comprehension.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler _"re.compile('\s+') works only because \s is not a recognized escape sequence."_ As a string or as a RE ? A RE, for me is a string used in search(), match(), compile() etc. ``re.compile('\\s+')`` works as well although **'\\s'** is an escaped string. But it is not an escaped RE. eh eh...

Comment: Yes, because `\\ ` IS a recognized escape sequence, therefore it is silently substituted with '\' by the python compiler - therefore it is equivalent to `\s`. `\\ ` for example is a recognized escape sequence, so in a regular expression you are forced to escape it: `\\\\ ` - or use a raw string `r'\\'`. See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: @Alexander Gessler I think it's the contrary. To compile a character meaning 'whitespace', the compiler must read a RE being the sequence of RE-characters **'a antislash'** then **'s'**. To obtain such a RE, we must write a **string** (we can't do nothing else than writing strings... but the compiler eats REs) that is ``'\\s'`` . So I should write ``'\\s'``. But I know that when the interpreter meets an antislash in a string, it internally represents it as ``\\`` : the proof is that if you define ``ch = 'ab\yz'`` and do ``print repr(ch)`` , you obtain **'ab\\yz'**.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler So, the compiler doesn't silent anything, it reads what is passed to it and interpret it as it must

Comment: @Alexander Gessler In fact, what you describe (``\\`` substituted with ``\``) is the mental operation we do to reach the representation that seems correct to our comprehension, but I think that Python does an opposite representation. And finally, in the end, when I think about all that, I reach a point.. where... I don't understand anything more... and I'am no more sure to understand the things correctly. I only know that I can write RE without rawing them and I have very few problems doing that

Comment: @eyquem: best practice with regexes is to use raw strings (r""), then you don't have to be concerned with which backslash escapes are interpreted lexically in string constants.  Your "\\y" example comes out different if you try "\\t", for example.

Comment: `repr(ch)` aims to produce valid Python code, so it prints the escape sequences (even if they are not explicitly needed, as in your sample - remember, it's strongly recommended to always escape single backslashes, so `repr`'s behaviour is good style): `eval(repr(ch))==ch` holds true. But internally, Python does not represent escaped characters by two characters - it just inserts the corresponding character code.

I think you got this all a bit wrong - consider re-reading the docs.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder @Alexander Gessler I think you are right. The problem is that when I read you, I don't understand. And the second problem is that, as I said, after a moment, when I read again what I wrote,I don't understand anymore ! It seems to me that I never really understand all these questions to the core. The fact is that when I try to use raw string as RE, I get into a muddle. So I code my RE without raw strings. I don't pretend everybody must do like me. And I wish to be free to code as I prefer.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder @Alexander Gessler I read quantities of times the explanations of Kuchling on the Backslash Plague (http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) My perplexity comes from the sentence: _"In short, to match a literal backslash, one has to write ``'\\\\'`` as the RE string, ``because the regular expression must be \\``, and each backslash must be expressed as ``\\`` inside a regular Python string literal."_ Well, I don't care, I code without raw string and it works, I 'm happy. I don't want to bother you more with this subject. Have a nice day

Comment: @Alexander Gessler _"But internally, Python does not represent escaped characters by two characters"_ I do believe, too